jq command to iterate on JSON array with values having space
Input filename is project.json, and its content is:
{
  "package": [
    {
      "path": "src",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "name": "Sample",
  "replacements": [
    {
      "filename": "/src/main/filename.xml",
      "stringToReplace": "SFP_VARIABLE_A",
      "replaceWith": "SFP_VARIABLE_A"
    },
    {
      "filename": "/src/main/file name 1.xml",
      "stringToReplace": "SECURE_VARIABLE_B",
      "replaceWith": "SECURE_VARIABLE_B",
      "allowUnsetEnvVariable": true
    },
    {
      "filename": "/src/main/file name 2.xml",
      "stringToReplace": "SFP_VARIABLE_C",
      "replaceWith": "SFP_VARIABLE_C"
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sourceApiVersion": "61.0"
}

The requirement is to validate that value of field "replaceWith" should start either with 'SFP_' or 'SECURE_', and none of objects in array "replacements" should have a field "allowUnsetEnvVariable"
filename="project.json"
if [[ ! -f "$filename" || ! -s "$filename" ]]; then return 1;fi

for item in $(cat $filename | jq -c ".replacements[]" ); do
    echo $item

    # USE ITEM FOR STRING REPLACEMENT AND VALIDATION
    # replaceWithEnv=$(echo $item | jq -r ".replaceWithEnv\"")
done

The output I get trims the spaces in "/src/main/CO Target System.xml":
item = {"filename":"/src/main/filename.xml","stringToReplace":"SFP_VARIABLE_A","replaceWith":"SFP_VARIABLE_A"}
item = {"filename":"/src/main/file
jq: parse error: Unfinished string at EOF at line 2, column 0
jq: parse error: Unfinished string at EOF at line 2, column 0
item = name
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
item = 1.xml","stringToReplace":"SECURE_VARIABLE_B","replaceWith":"SECURE_VARIABLE_B","allowUnsetEnvVariable":true}
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6
item = {"filename":"/src/main/file
jq: parse error: Unfinished string at EOF at line 2, column 0
jq: parse error: Unfinished string at EOF at line 2, column 0
item = name
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
item = 2.xml","stringToReplace":"SFP_VARIABLE_C","replaceWith":"SFP_VARIABLE_C"}
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6


Use a while read loop to read line by line: while read -r item; do echo "$item"; done < <(jq -c '.replacements[]' "$filename")

You are going to want to use some tool that understands XML to make the replacement, so this argues heavily for a language that has a JSON parser and an XML parser available as libraries. I wouldn't bother with jq here.

Generally I'd agree that XML needs to be parsed with an XML parser, but in this case, if the stringToReplace and replaceWith doesn't involve markup, you probably don't need to actually parse the XML.  I also think jq is the perfect tool for pulling the information you need out of the json, I don't really think there's an elegant way to do this without it

An elegant solution could be using xq, a jq wrapper for XML that comes with kislyuk/yq, reading the XML file(s) as standard file argument(s), and the JSON file via the --slurpfile flag.

Thank you for the valuable input, but in my case jq is not able to get the filename i.e., "/src/main/CO Target System.xml" correctly. Unless I have the path, I cannot do anything further.

@pmf thank you for the suggestion, it worked using while read

The problem you are having is caused by the way you have constructed the loop: for item in ... is simply inappropriate here. You don't want to iterate over the tokens.
Instead, as pointed out by @pmf, you could use a loop along the following lines:
< "$filename" jq -c ".replacements[]" | while read -r item ; do
    printf "%s\n" "$item"
done    


You might be better off without any shell loop at all; you might even be able to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to do using jq alone.  If you gave a bit more information about your high-level goals, that would probably help everyone.

I have edited the sample JSON file in my primary post/question. The requirement is to validate that value of field "replaceWith" should start either with 'SFP_' or 'SECURE_', and none of objects in array "replacements" should have a field "allowUnsetEnvVariable".
